# Merging n/k sorted lists in nlog(n/k) - python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

I have round(n/k) sorted sublists, meaning that the length of each sublist is k (and a single list with less than k length). I need to merge them into a single n-length sorted list using the classic O(m+n) merge function, so it would take O(n*log(n/k)).

I had two implementations, one with recursion (which seems to be right, but wouldn't work unless I'd change the recursion depth, which I am not allowed to, and I don't understand why actually, when the input list has no more than 10 sublists, each in length k=3):

```
def merge_sorted_blocks(lst):
  i=0
  pairs_lst=[]
  n=len(lst)
  while i<n-1:
    pairs_lst.append(merge(lst[i],lst[i+1]))
    i+=2
  if n%2>0:
    pairs_lst.append(lst[n-1])
  if type(pairs_lst[0])!=list:
    return pairs_lst
  return merge_sorted_blocks(pairs_lst)
```

and one with consecutive the output list with the next sublist:

```
def merge_sorted_blocks(lst):
  pairs_lst=[]
  for i in lst:
    pairs_lst=merge(pairs_lst,i)
  return pairs_lst
```

but I don't thing it has the desired complexity, more like O(n*(k+2k+...))=O(n^2)).
I found this thread which suggests it does but I don't understand how:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881599/on-log-k-for-merging-of-k-lists-with-total-of-n-elements

Is there something I'm missing, regarding each of these solutions?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Have you read about heap data structure? (Here min-heap)

Answer (score 1):

For the second algorithm your computation has a fallacy. Moreover, the thread that you mentioned has some differences with your question.

You have `k` sublist with size of `n/k`. Since the complexity of `merge` function for two sets with size of `n1` and `n2` is `O(n1 + n2)`, computation complexity of first merge of two sublist is `O(2 * n/k)`, and complexity of the current sublist with the third sublist is `O(3 * n/k)`. Hence, the complexity of the second algorithm is `O(2*(n/k) + 3*(n/k) + ... + k*(n/k)) = O(nk)`.

For the first implementation, some details are missed. For example, if there is just one set (for example for the last step) the loop will be failed.

In addition, complexity analysis for the first algorithm is not accurate. If you want to implement the referenced algorithm, the algorithm is `O(n/k * log(k))`.

Comment: as I mentioned the size of each sublist is k, and all of the sublists consist together for n terms, meaning there are n/k sublists